# fread escapes quotes when not necessary

Tags: r, csv, escaping, fread, quote

I'm reading a csv file with quoted fields using the `fread` function. In some of the fields escaped quotes (`\"`) appear. I don't understand why the `fread` function escapes these quotes that are already escaped.

I reproduce the behavior with a simple example. I created a file with a single line and a single field:

```
"Hello \"World\" "
```

If I run the following R command:

```
table <- fread(input = "/tmp/quoteprova.csv", header=FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

the table variable will look like this:

```
                  V1
1: Hello \\"World\\"
```

I would expect instead this result:

```
                V1
1: Hello \"World\"
```

Am I missing to specify some options in order to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You are geting what you want. `\\"` is two characters: a normal character `\` and a `"`. Because `\` is used to escape special characters and `\*` would be interpreted as a special character that are escaped with `\`. Thefore the additional `\` (the first one) here will tell you that the second `\` is not used to escape `"` and should be treated as is.

see this example:

```
> nchar('\\"')
[1] 2
> nchar('\"')
[1] 1
```

also [this R faq](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_88.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I disagree. If fread is reading a csv file where fields are double-quoted, it should expect that in that csv file double quotes inside the fields are already escaped (otherwise it cannot properly read the file). Therefore there's no point for the fread function in escaping the double-quotes a second time

Comment: @rlar, the link in the original answer was incorrect. Please see the updated link. We should discriminate the "character strings" and "representations of character strings". `fread` didn't escape it again. Instead R escape the "\" in order to tell you that that "\" is just a "\", not used to escpae the character following it.